# xcode UICollectionView scroll to default selected item at start

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have created collection view in view controller. I have written code for  delegate and datasource methods. Now I want to start the view at a particular index, lets say 2.I have written following code in viewDidLoad method. However, it is throwing exception and my app is getting terminated in the emulator.

```
NSIndexPath *a=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:18];
[self.myFullScreenCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:a atScrollPosition:10 animated:NO];
```

Comment: Which error message do you get? There must be something printed in the console? If you set an exception breakpoint then you may have to click on continue in the debugger one or two times or so before the error message is acutally printed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a valid enum value in following:

```
[self.myFullScreenCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:a atScrollPosition:10 animated:NO];
```

Here the second parameter needs to be filled with an integer that belongs to following enum **UICollectionViewScrollPosition**:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UICollectionViewScrollPosition) {
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone                 = 0,

    // The vertical positions are mutually exclusive to each other, but are bitwise or-able with the horizontal scroll positions.
    // Combining positions from the same grouping (horizontal or vertical) will result in an NSInvalidArgumentException.
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop                  = 1 << 0,
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically   = 1 << 1,
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom               = 1 << 2,

    // Likewise, the horizontal positions are mutually exclusive to each other.
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft                 = 1 << 3,
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally = 1 << 4,
    UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight                = 1 << 5
};
```

Try using one of these standard enum values, this might help. I think 10 is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling to get this work done & now I have it fully functional by using the default method of CollectionView.

Here it is how to scroll the collection view to the respective item index. Let's assume that I want the collection view to scroll to an item at index 3, here is the code.

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:3 inSection:0]
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone
                                    animated:NO];
```

The key factor was `UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone` enum value.

Comment: worked for me but I had to put it in viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear